# QGIS: select multiples attributes which contains different words using select by expression

Tags: qgis, select-by-expression

I would like to select multiple attributes which contains some specific text ("Bus", "Car", and "Motorbike") from the same field ("commodity") using Select by Expression function in QGIS. My version is QGIS 3.24.0

In case I just want to select the attributes of field "commodity" which contains the text "Bus", I use *like* operator:

```
 "commodity" like '%Bus%'
```

However, I also want the rows which contains other words as "motorbike" and "car". Among other things, I am trying the following:

```
"commodity" like ('%Bus%', '%Motorbike%', '%Car%')
```

However, it does not work. Any idea of how I should proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to chain your LIKE expression with the OR operator so your expression become :

```
"commodity" like '%Bus%' OR "commodity" like '%Motorbike%' OR "commodity" like '%Car%'
```

(Separating value with comma work for the IN operator but not with like)

Comment: It works. Thank you!